# Select rows based on values of the other rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to select rows in pandas df based on the values of other rows. Clarifying idea, let`s imagine we have a table, consisting of two columns:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 10 | 9 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 9 | 10 |
| 7 | 10 |

I want to select all tuples of rows, for which values in column B are bigger *than in current row*, while values in column A are smaller. So from this table, I would have two different sets:  ((1,2), (0,3)) and ((10, 9), (9, 10), (7, 10)). Can I achieve this using pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think the only way to do it is using itertuples()/iterrows(). Here is the solution:

```
 all_matching_dfs = []
 for row in df.itertuples():
    matching_df = df.loc[(df['B' > row.b) & (df['A'] < row.A)]
    all_matching_dfs.append(matching_df)
 # skipping here the part where I process all_mathcing_dfs
```

Although the solution is not that fast.